# Est-ce correct de dire « je vous appelle à vous » ?

Tags: pronoms, prépositions, ordre-des-mots, constructions

> Je vous appelle à vous

Un ami m'a dit cette phrase, mais je n'arrive pas à déterminer si elle est effectivement correcte ou pas. À l'oreille, ça sonne bizarre mais je ne me rappelle pas de « règle » de français qui interdit ce genre de construction.

Comment: Il n'a rien dit d'autre? C'est sa phrase entière? Si c'est le cas, cette phrase n'a pas de sens effectivement. Mais si il y a un verbe après, ça peut en avoir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appeler est transitif direct dans l'expression *appeler quelqu'un*.

La règle qui n'a pas été respectée a donc consisté à utiliser *appeler **à** quelqu'un* (transitif indirect).

Quand on souhaite insister sur le fait que c'est *vous* et pas quelqu'un d'autre qui est appelé, la forme standard est,

> Je vous appelle, vous !

On entend parfois *je vous appelle à vous* ou *je t'appelle à toi* (transitif indirect) avec le même sens, mais c'est du français très relâché (enfants, parler des « banlieues », etc.)

J'ai trouvé quelques occurrences similaires dans un [forum](https://grossesse.aufeminin.com/forum/courrier-resultats-trisomie-21-fd3993032):

> ...ils m'écrivent que les résultats sont entre les mains de mon gynéco et que donc, il faut que **je l'appelle à lui** pour avoir les résultats.

et aussi [là](http://forums.remede.org/la_profession_de_manipulateur_radio/sujet_56474.html):

> ...sur Lyon tu ne dois pas être la seule à chercher du boulot je pense non ? alors pourquoi **on t'appelle à toi**, qui plus est 6 fois ?

Dans le même style, on peut aussi entendre :

> C'est à toi que je te parle.

au lieu de l'attendu

> C'est à toi que je parle.

Answer (score 2):

Non, cette phrase n'est pas correcte. Peut-être est-ce une confusion avec l'expression "en appeler à quelqu'un" qui signifie "recourir à quelqu'un". Dans les autres cas, "appeler" est transitif, donc on peut dire soit

> Je vous appelle, vous. Pourquoi n'est-ce pas vous qui répondez ?

soit

> J'en appelle à vous. Votre aide me sera précieuse.

Answer (score 0):

**A** C'est une façon très maladroite de confirmer à la personne que l'on appelle qu'il s'agit bien d'elle. Selon un ton normal d'élocution on peut dire comme suit;

> C'est bien vous que j'appelle. *ou*
>   Vous êtes bien la personne que j'appelle.

On peut aussi dire comme suit, de façon seulement légèrement moins formelle;

> C'est vous que j'appelle, oui.

Il faut noter la possibilité « Je vous appelle, vous! » (voir [réponse par jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32455/17649)) et se rappeler qu'elle n'est pas tout à fait usuelle et peut occasionnellement, en plus que d'être moins courtoise généralement, être soit plus ou moins abrupte (« vous » est alors prononcé avec plus ou moins de force ou même avec véhémence), soit empreinte d'un ton de remontrance joviale. On entend assez souvent la variante suivante;

> Je vous appelle, oui! vous!

**B** S'il s'agit tout simplement de rendre une personne consciente qu'un appel lui est destiné, avant même qu'elle se pose la question les formes sont modifiées légèrement. On n'utilise plus l'adverbe « bien ».